# Installing the matrix theme

Tags: 14.04, themes

I have been trying to install matrix, first it was in the desktop then I moved it to /usr/share/themes but simply doesn't work by running the install.sh file in it and I have all the specification in the Readme.txt

Comment: What do you think the theme is?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the theme folder to `~/.local/share/themes`, and activate it using [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/).